# Is there any control plugin for windows form to make a better windows form design?

Tags: winforms, desktop-application

I need to improve my windows form application UI, is there any free plugin that can make my application better? please advise.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out Component Factory (Krypton): https://github.com/ComponentFactory/Krypton

They have a free toolkit you can use to make your app aesthetically pleasing.

Comment: Hai Evan, I've checked the component and it looks great! thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too ambiguous.  You need to define "better".

However, to take a stab at answering it, fundamentally no there isn't.  Good design with regards to look and feel and UX is baked in from the start.  There is no magic wand or plug-in as we're calling it here to spruce things up in a WinForm environment.

Comment: Yup, what I mean by a better UI is using a better control, icon, etc.